# Change swipe up home button shortcuts

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts

I have a Nexus 5 with ParanoidAndroid and I'd like to change that Google Now shortcut to lightbulb, how can I do it?

[image: smaller screen]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [SwipeUp Utility](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.AdrianCampos.swipeuputility) to change the behaviour of the search action (swiping the home button) to launch a different app or shortcut.

I've contributed to this app (I helped the author fix a bug) but I've no financial interest in it.